Resolved promise but unable to insert data into react project
Using contentful as my CMS and retrieving my content using code below
const ProductsGrid = () => {
    let imageURL;
    
    client.getEntries().then(function (entries) {
        entries.items.forEach(function (entry) {
            imageURL = entry.fields.image.fields.file.url
            console.log(imageURL)
        }
        )
    })

This works and i can see my imageURL's in console
//images.ctfassets.net/zpu537igy6hd/10jOjKpdTYAYRVc197KlAs/60910da04dceab7acda47c042261776e/397526804_263713576623932_2944288645324919698_n.jpg
ProductsGrid.jsx:17 //images.ctfassets.net/zpu537igy6hd/2fat5G5gnOIT00YAdoSVZg/ea3f8c44b62cf977bc8a0d5b3e4eeea7/397492507_267421149586508_6988846565487064728_n.jpg
The problem is I cannot get this imageURL to render out in my react project
return (
                      <figure className='px-4 pt-4'>
                            <img
                                src={imageURL}
                                alt={title}
                                className='rounded-xl h-64 md:h-48 w-full object-cover'
                            />
                        </figure>

imageURL is returning undefined instead of my URL links.
Am I resolving my Promises incorrectly?
Thanks

don't you need something like a useEffect to load the data and useState or useReducer to render your data?

Tried with useState and useEffect
`const [image, setImage] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
    const client = createClient({
        accessToken: 's4HlIPhwB7xN4RkQvXB2xEu8l28',
        space: 'zpy6hd',
    })
    client.getEntries().then(function (entries) {
        entries.items.forEach(function (entry) {
            setImage(entry.fields.image.fields.file.url)
            console.log(image)
        }
        )
    })
})`


The code above on my console.log(image) gives me 2 undefined first then my images, so I'm assuming the promises are not been resolved before i am trying to render them in React or is it something else? Thanks

That’s right. On the first render, the promise won’t be resolved yet. You would normally display some kind of loading indicator in that state. Also bear in mind that code will overwrite the image on each iteration of forEach. You might want to store the entire array as your state.

A state is a must.
Since the asynchronous call to get the url will complete later than the component is rendered, the url at the time of initial render will be undefined in this case. Now the requirement is that we need to have another render as soon as the url has been fetched. Therefore in order to trigger a new render, there would need a state. The url fetched will be set against this state, and this change in state will cause another render and the desired output.
Please see below two sets of sample codes.
a. Without a state
export default function App() {
  let url;

  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('http://someurl'), 1000);
  }).then((newurl) => (url = newurl));

  return <>{url ? url : 'no url'}</>;
}

Test run
On loading the App

b. With a state
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [url, setURL] = useState();

  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('http://someurl'), 1000);
  }).then((url) => setURL(url));

  return <>{url ? url : 'no url'}</>;
}

Test run
After the set timeout of 1s.

